# Drop "faulty" lines of pandas dataframe based on their type and value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that includes a column of date and time values and another column containing some measured values (float). However, during some measurements, an error occured, resulting in some weird entries - example below (these include a repeated part of the datetime object which is interpreted as string, incomplete datetime object, a completely random string, a missing value or a value for the other column which is way out of range (measured values are mostly between 10 and 50, but sometimes I get a zero or a value like 100).

extract from the large dataset (loaded as pandas dataframe):

```
                                      t                          baaa
0                      13/11/2014 23:43                          17.6
1                      13/11/2014 23:44                          17.7
2   2014-11-13 23:452014-11-13 23:45:00                          17.7
3                      13/11/2014 23:46                          17.7
4                      14/11/2014 00:34                            16
5                      14/11/2014 00:35                          15.9
6                                   :00                          17.7
7                      14/11/2014 01:25                          14.9
8                      14/11/2014 01:26                          14.9
9                                     0                            80
10                     14/11/2014 02:16                          14.3
11                     14/11/2014 02:17                          14.3
12                                  NaN  AA550112209500080009002855AA
13                     14/11/2014 03:09                            13
14                      009000B002B55AA                           NaN
15                     14/11/2014 02:19                          14.3
16                     14/11/2014 03:59                          12.6
17                     14/11/2014 04:00                          12.6
18                     14/11/2014 05:41                          11.7
19                     14/11/2014 05:42                          11.7
20                                    0                           140
21                     14/11/2014 04:53                          12.2
```

examples of all types of faulty entries are here.
How can I get rid of the faulty lines?
My idea was to do an if loop, setting the condition that the 't' column should be a datetime object and the 'baaa' columns should be a float > 0 and < 60. If the condition is not fulfilled, I would replace the value with `np.nan` and eventually use the `dropna` function.

```
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'], format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce')
df.iloc[:,1] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,1], errors='coerce')    
for line in df.iloc[:,1]:  
    if (line < 60) & (line > 0):
       line = line
   else:
       line = np.nan
    # not assigning this new value! :( 

    df = df.dropna(subset = df.columns.values, how='any', inplace=True)
```

This seems to have solved most of the problems except the condition that the line needs to be lower than 60.
I must have a wrong syntax? Or what is wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering, instead [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) you can add new (third) condition with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) - get all not `NaN` values in column `t`. `NaN` values in first column are filtered by first and second condition:

```
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'], format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce')
df.iloc[:,1] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,1], errors='coerce')  
df = df[(df.iloc[:,1] < 60) & (df.iloc[:,1] > 0) & (df['t'].notnull())]

print (df)
                     t  baaa
0  2014-11-13 23:43:00  17.6
1  2014-11-13 23:44:00  17.7
3  2014-11-13 23:46:00  17.7
4  2014-11-14 00:34:00  16.0
5  2014-11-14 00:35:00  15.9
7  2014-11-14 01:25:00  14.9
8  2014-11-14 01:26:00  14.9
10 2014-11-14 02:16:00  14.3
11 2014-11-14 02:17:00  14.3
13 2014-11-14 03:09:00  13.0
15 2014-11-14 02:19:00  14.3
16 2014-11-14 03:59:00  12.6
17 2014-11-14 04:00:00  12.6
18 2014-11-14 05:41:00  11.7
19 2014-11-14 05:42:00  11.7
21 2014-11-14 04:53:00  12.2
```